# Extended WPF Toolkit change ChildWindow position in code

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

Both `WindowContainer` and `ChildWindow` of the Extended WPF Toolkit have `Left` and `Top` properties available in XAML but neither of those two properties are available in code behind.

How can we change the position of `WindowContainer` or `ChildWindow` from code if these properties are not exposed?

```
private void VerifyWindowSize(Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Primitives.WindowContainer wc)
{
    if (wc == null) return;
    if (wc.Width > screen.WorkingArea.Width)
    {
        wc.Width = screen.WorkingArea.Width;
        //wc.Left = screen.WorkingArea.Left; // Cannot resolve symbol Left
    }
    if (!(wc.Height > screen.WorkingArea.Height)) return;
    wc.Height = screen.WorkingArea.Height;
    //wc.Top = screen.WorkingArea.Top;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WindowContainer](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Primitives.WindowContainer.html) is a [Canvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx), therefore its own `Left` and `Top` dependency properties are [attached](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview). They are not meant for the `WindowContainer` itself, but for its children.
If you want to set - for example - the `Left` attached property for a child of a `Canvas`, you can use the related method [SetLeft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setleft(v=vs.110).aspx).

On the other side the [ChildWindow](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ChildWindow.html) control has its own [Left](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Primitives.WindowControl~Left.html) and [Top](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit~Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Primitives.WindowControl~Top.html) properties, they are *not* attached and you can use it in your code without any problem.

I hope it can help you.